# How to reset a variable in rust smart contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a lookupMap

```
pub struct App {
   update_user_ids: LookupMap<u128, u128>,
}
```

I want to reset the update_user_ids, how should I do that?

This below function does not work if I give key_prefix id "f657bf68" same as that used in initialization of update_user_ids in #[init] pub fn new().

```
pub fn reset (&mut self) {
        self.update_user_ids = LookupMap::new(b"f657bf68".to_vec());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by design, [`LookupMap`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.LookupMap.html) does not have a way to delete all its entries since it does not know the keys. You can only insert and delete entries by known keys. If you know the keys, you can call `self.update_user_ids.remove()` in a loop. If your intention is to start from scratch, I recommend you recreate an account to wipe the state completely; otherwise, use [`UnorderedMap`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.UnorderedMap.html) or [`TreeMap`](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.TreeMap.html) which have `clear()` implementation.

Comment: clear() doesn't seem a good idea as it will loop through all elements and number of elements can be large in 10000. https://docs.rs/near-sdk/2.0.0/src/near_sdk/collections/unordered_map.rs.html#191-198 Is it fine to use a new key_prefix instead?

Comment: You can use a new prefix, but this will leave the old entries in the storage, so you won’t get back the balance reserved for storage. There is currently no way to wipe storage efficiently. You may champion the NEP to improve the situation

Comment: Ya, got the problem. Thank You.